# Groups share the same name; I need to tell them apart

Tags: 7, organic-groups

Using [Organic Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) for the first time and I've run into an issue.

I'm building the group hierarchy and I have two groups with the same name. Right now it's only two groups but there is the possibility of this happening again in the future. Obviously I cannot rename one of them.

Here is the general hierarchy:

- Level 1 (Brand) with 2 groups

  - Level 2 (Location) with 15 groups

    - Level 3 (Property) with >50 groups

I have one location that is shared on both brands so I have two groups with the same name that are technically different because the parent group is different.

How do I differentiate between the two groups?

Comment: Differentiate how? And when? (what context?)

Comment: The field where you select the parent group, views, basically anywhere you would display the group name. I think I'm on the right track for the group selector field on the nodes...going to modify the entity reference field info.

Comment: Or if groups are entities in their own right, you might be able to `hook_entity_info_alter` it and alter the label callback (maybe append the level or node id or something). In theory that should sort it everywhere that it's used by code that behaves well

Comment: I'll give that a shot, changing the field selector to a view didn't work. OG threw an error because it is expecting it's own Entity Selection Mode.